# HTML Form using JS to validate Email, Validation works but form still submits

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to validate the email field of a form that uses php to send form information to a set of emails. I'm using Javascript to validate the email and it is working.

The problem is, even after the validation returns false the form still processes the information and sends the emails, i would love some guidance as I can't find the error i'm making.

**Here's the HTML code i'm using for the form:**

```
            <form id="formulario-submit" onsubmit="return Validacion();" action="procesarsolicitud.php" method="POST">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input   type="text" value="Nombre*" id="nombre" name="nombre" onclick='this.value = "";'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="Apellido*" id="apellido" name="apellido" onclick='this.value = "";'>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!--<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviar" alt="enviar">-->

                        <button name="enviar" value="Submit" type="submit" id="enviar" alt="enviar" width="100">
```

**Here's the JS code i'm using to validate the email:**

```
    <script>
function Validacion()
{
var x=document.forms["formulario-submit"]["email"].value;
var arroba=x.indexOf("@");
var punto=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (arroba<1 || punto<arroba+2 || punto+2>=x.length)
 {
  alert("Not a valid Email.");
  email.focus();
  return false;
 }
}
</script>
```

**Here's the PHP code (on a separate PHP file called procesarsolicitud.php) i'm using to process the data and send the email:**

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];    
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = '
    <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h3>Form Data::</h3>
        <tr>
          <td width="200"><b>Nombre:</b></td>
          <td>'.$nombre.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="200"><b>Apellido:</b></td>
          <td>'.$apellido.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="200"><b>Email:</b></td>
          <td>'.$email.'</td>
        </tr>                                  
        <tr>
        </tr>                                                                                           
      </table><br />

    </body>
    </html>
    ';

    // multiple recipients

    $to='email1@email.com,email2@email.com';

    // subject
    $subject = ' Email Subject';

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n".
    'From: Email <info@email.com>' . "\r\n";
    echo "MessageExample";



    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider `<input type=email>` and a browser shim for backwards support rather than custom Javascript code for verification.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use JS to validate form in the first place. To be precise.. if you are doing that, you have to check the input server side as well (you could also use AJAX call to validate form on server-side, then you could reuse the same sanitizers/validators).

Regarding your specific issue, SOF "Ask Question" is not a search engine. You should invest some time looking before asking questions. Your question has been asked (e.g., first result from google "onsubmit form return false" http://webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=175736; first result from SOF [onSubmit returning false is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543963/onsubmit-returning-false-is-not-working)) numerous times.

p.s. Check Console (ref. to Firebug for more info) if there are any errors.

Comment: If you use JS validation first, it lowers server load for input that obviously won't validate.  Even just checking that something is entered in required fields is better than wasted requests.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Agreed. You should definitely use client-side validation if you feel inclined to do so. This comes with the obvious caveat that you MUST ALSO validate server-side because users can turn off JavaScript. server-side validation: REQUIRED, client-side validation: a nice extra.

Comment: I am asking for guidance or a solution not suggestions or links to similar threads that i've probably looked over but couldn't help me fix my problem. I'll look into client-side validation after i can solve this, Thanks for your help.