# my onsubmit="return onNewUserRegistrationCheck(this);" still submits form on FALSE

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I've read several SO posts on this issue and the one I found with a *possible* explanation was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543963/onsubmit-returning-false-is-not-working) one.
A response in that post says "Browsers do not call the onSubmit event on the form if you call submit() programmatically."

I'm not sure if this is the operative thing affecting my form.

My code onsubmit="return onNewUserRegistrationCheck(this);" is 100% working 
-- the call to onNewUserRegistrationCheck(this)  is 100% occurring.

Here's that code:

```
      function onNewUserRegistrationCheck(theForm)
      {

          alert("In onNewUserRegistrationCheck()");

          if(theForm.loginname.value == "<?php echo Labels::$DEFAULTLOGINEMAILLABEL ?>" 
              || theForm.password.value == "<?php echo Labels::$DEFAULTPASSWORDLABEL ?>" )
          {  
              alert("returning false now, so -- HOPEFULLY the form doesn't submit");
              return false;
          }
     }
```

Here's the form:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return onNewUserRegistrationCheck(this);"
                 class="registerFormStyles" name="registerForm" id="regform"
                 action="regTheNewUser.php" method="post">
         <input type="text" id="loginname" name="<?php  echo Labels::$USERNAMELABEL ?>"
               style="width:260px" value="<?php echo Labels::$DEFAULTLOGINEMAILLABEL ?>" />

         <input type="password" placeholder="<?php echo Labels::$DEFAULTPASSWORDLABEL ?>" 
                  id="password" name="<?php echo Labels::$PASSWORD ?>"
            style="width:220px" class="inactive" />

         <input type="hidden" name="newUserRegister" id="newUserRegisterId">

         <input type="image" name="registerButton" value="Register" class="login-button-landing" 
                    onclick="document.registerForm.submit();">
    </form>
```

Notice I use a type="image" and do a programmatic submit().  According to some SO posts, the result of
a programmatic submit() like I'm doing is this:  **'Browsers do not call the onSubmit event on the form if you call submit() programmatically'**

However I'm seeing 2 alert boxes when I click on my name="registerButton" pseudo-submit button:

```
  alert box #1 pops up and says:  "In onNewUserRegistrationCheck()"
```

then....

```
  alert box #2 pops up and says:  "returning false now, so -- HOPEFULLY the form doesn't submit"
```

Those 2 alert boxes appear when I click my name="registerButton"  button on the form.
So I must (?) misunderstand what is meant in the posts I've read that say 
'calling submit() doesn't fire the onsubmit event'.

The bottom line is the form is still submitted to the file "regTheNewUser.php"
even though you can see that 'return false' occurred because of the alert message
being seen **"returning false now, so -- HOPEFULLY the form doesn't submit"**

How can I stop the form being submitted *without* using a type="submit" button?
I've proved to myself that my **onsubmit="return onNewUserRegistrationCheck(this);"**
is 100% being called.  I return false but the form is submitted anyway.

How can I stop the form being submitted when I find invalid form text entry
and why doesn't 'return false' above STOP my form submission?

Comment: You might try `onsubmit="onNewUserRegistrationCheck(this); return false;"` just to see if it works. If so then at least you know it's a problem with your function's logic.

Comment: Will try that.  However look at the above code, alert("returning false now, so -- HOPEFULLY the form doesn't submit");
              return false;    -- there's no way I will see 'HOPEFULLY..etc' and NOT return false.  And I am seeing the 'HOPEFULLY.....' so the 'return false' MUST be happening -- if you look at the code there seems no way for the 'HOPEFULLY...' to appear unless 'return false' occurs right after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

onclick="document.registerForm.submit();"

!!!

type=image IS a submit and 
document.registerForm.submit() does not trigger the onsubmit event handler!

So the click first triggers the submission regardless, then the event handler kicks in because it is a submit button and then the form is sent to the server from the first submt

Comment: and 'replace it with 'input type="submit" ??   I mentioned in the post above "How can I stop the form being submitted without using a type="submit" button?".......not sure if you saw that part.  I need to stop the form submission CONDITIONALLY, if I find bad input, and without using type="submit" input.

Comment: Wow -- I was 100% unaware that type="image" is also a submit.  Thank you for that, that is a biggie for me, very helpful. thanks M.

Comment: mplungjan, you're an intelligent genius with this, that solved the problem, just outstanding stuff.  The posts I read, the things I tried. My entire problem was that I was under the impression that only the type="submit" was a submit-capable element.  This is a big deal for me as so much of this stuff is new -- thanks man!

Comment: PS You REALLY should check the login credentials on the server. Your code can be simply viewed using view-source or firebug and anyone can log in

Answer (score 1):

In your post you have used

1. Input type = "Image"  -- Which has the same behavior as that of the input type="submit" so on clicking the image it is triggering the onsubmit event. You have returned false from the onsubmit event handler function, and the onsubmit handler is registered with the form so the return value is sent to the form and the submit action of the form is stopped.

   But you said that your form is getting submitted because,
2. In the image you have registered the onclick event on which you have called the submit() method programatically, so your form is getting submitted.

In order to stop your form from being submitted on returning false just remove the onclick event handler from the image and replace it with the below code

```
<input type="image" name="registerButton" value="Register" class="login-button-landing" >
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: AmGates, thanks, +1, I've already fixed it with the kind help of mplungjan.  Thank you for taking the time to reassert the correct way to make this work.