# Get the results of the domain check with AJAX or JS instead of refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a API script from my hosting provider and with this `.php` script I can only check if a Domain name is availble or not. But right now if I check a domain name, the page will refresh and then it will show the results.

But I want the results to show without refreshing. Is that possible? Can someone have a good solution for me?

**Here is the results portion:**

```
<center> <font color="#FFF "> <?=$result?> </font> </center>`
```

**And this is the whole `.php` script:**

```
<?php

require_once('Transip/DomainService.php');

if(isset($_GET['domain']) && strlen($_GET['domain']) > 0) {
    $domain = $_GET['domain'];

    try {
        // Request the availability of a domain by using the Transip_DomainService API;
        // we can get the following different statusses back with different meanings.
        $availability = Transip_DomainService::checkAvailability($domain);
        switch($availability) {
            case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_INYOURACCOUNT:
                $result = htmlspecialchars($domain) 
                            . ' is helaas al <font color="red">bezet</font>, verhuizen is niet mogelijk  ';
            break;

            case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_UNAVAILABLE:
                $result = htmlspecialchars($domain) 
                            . ' is ge-lockt, verhuizen is niet mogelijk!';
            break;

            case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_FREE:
                $result = htmlspecialchars($domain) 
                            . ' is <font color="green">beschikbaar!</font> <br><a href="http://xcoder.eu/coming/login.html" target="_blank">Klik hier</a> en registreer direct je domeinnaam!  ';
            break;


            case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_NOTFREE:
                $result = htmlspecialchars($domain) 
                            . ' is helaas al <font color="red">bezet</font>, verhuizen is mogelijk  ';
            break;
        }
    }
    catch(SoapFault $e) {
        // It is possible that an error occurs when connecting to the TransIP Soap API,
        // those errors will be thrown as a SoapFault exception.
        $result = 'Oeps... Vul een geldige domeinnaam in. ';
    }
}
else {
    $domain = '';
    $result = '';
}
?>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
</head>
<body style="background:transparent">
<form name="domainChecker"  id="notifyMe"  class="news-form" style="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input  type="text" style="text-align:center;" name="domain" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($domain)?>" required type="text" id="mail-sub" placeholder="Check of jouw domeinnaam beschikbaar is!" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Check of jouw domeinnaam beschikbaar is!'" class="form-control email srequiredField"  required >
            <button class="btn btn-lg submit" style="background:#ffc000;border:#eeb300;color:black" type="submit">Controleer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <center><font color="#FFF "><?=$result?></font></center>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Xcoder would it be possible for you to post this file Transip/DomainService.php otherwise I can likely make some smaller segment of php to return a response and have the html in the Main.php use jquery and retrieve the result.

Comment: Yes offcourse can you mail me at x@xcoder.eu then i wil reply you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure @Chad Collins will have something that works, but I was in the middle of writing this quick script, so I figure I'll post it even though you have accepted his answer. You can try it...or not *(I have not tried it, so if it doesn't work, I will delete my answer)*:

**index.php**

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
</head>
<body style="background:transparent">
<form name="domainChecker"  id="notifyMe"  class="news-form" style="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" style="text-align:center;" name="domain" value="" required type="text" id="mail-sub" placeholder="Check of jouw domeinnaam beschikbaar is!" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Check of jouw domeinnaam beschikbaar is!'" class="form-control email srequiredField"  required >
            <button class="btn btn-lg submit" style="background:#ffc000;border:#eeb300;color:black" type="submit">Controleer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <center><font color="#FFF " id="resp"></font></center>
</form>
<script>
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
                url: 'checkdomain.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: 'post',
                success: function(response) {
                    var DataResp    =   JSON.parse(response);

                    // Access the domain with-> DataResp.domain
                    // Access the result with-> DataResp.result

                    if(DataResp.result)
                        $("#resp").html(DataResp.result);
                    else
                        $("#resp").html("Empty message here.");
                }
        });

        return false;
    });
</script>
</body>
```

**checkdomain.php**

```
<?php
function CheckDomain($domain = false)
    {
        $domain = trim($domain);

        if(empty($domain))
            return array("domain"=>false,"result"=>false);

        require_once('Transip/DomainService.php');

            try {
                // Request the availability of a domain by using the Transip_DomainService API;
                // we can get the following different statusses back with different meanings.
                $availability = Transip_DomainService::checkAvailability($domain);
                switch($availability) {
                    case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_INYOURACCOUNT:
                        $result = htmlspecialchars($domain).' is helaas al <font color="red">bezet</font>, verhuizen is niet mogelijk  ';
                    break;

                    case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_UNAVAILABLE:
                        $result = htmlspecialchars($domain).' is ge-lockt, verhuizen is niet mogelijk!';
                    break;

                    case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_FREE:
                        $result = htmlspecialchars($domain).' is <font color="green">beschikbaar!</font> <br><a href="http://xcoder.eu/coming/login.html" target="_blank">Klik hier</a> en registreer direct je domeinnaam!  ';
                    break;


                    case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_NOTFREE:
                        $result = htmlspecialchars($domain).' is helaas al <font color="red">bezet</font>, verhuizen is mogelijk  ';
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch(SoapFault $e) {
                // It is possible that an error occurs when connecting to the TransIP Soap API,
                // those errors will be thrown as a SoapFault exception.
                $result = 'Oeps... Vul een geldige domeinnaam in. ';
            }

        // Sorry, my original post didn't return anything here! Whoops!
        $response['domain'] =   (!empty($domain))? $domain: "";
        $response['result'] =   (!empty($result))? $result:"";

        return $response;
    }

    echo json_encode(CheckDomain((isset($_POST['domain']))? $_POST['domain']:""));
?>
```

Comment: Upvote from me @Rasclatt great quick example... One thing I would add that is a prevent.default jquery handler so the page doesnt submit / reload. $( "#notifyMe" ).submit(function( event ) {....

  // Stop form from submitting normally etc... 
  event.preventDefault();

Comment: Well, the `return false;` will have the same effect as the `prevent.default`. I generally return false when I do Ajax but I know `prevent.default` is probably the preferred method.

Comment: Are you sure about that? That hasnt worked in every browser for me in the past when dealing with submit buttons and forms. Its been my experience that 40% of the time, return false; has worked everytime.. {anchorman jokes on SO} probably dont go over great. :)

Comment: Hmmm, I will have to check that. I have never had anyone complain about returning false on any of the sites I have done, and I have done it a lot, so that is an interesting point I will have to do further research on!! Maybe there is a reason `prevent.default` is the preferred method!

Comment: Its probably a legacy issue that is no longer there... Ill have to try again some time.. but here is what I meant.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543963/onsubmit-returning-false-is-not-working

Comment: Well now I am paranoid about it, I'll have a complex about returning false in the future! Thanks a lot buddy! :D

Comment: NOW finally I get to LOL on SO ! :) dont even google it.. tons of SO posts saying that same thing.. and ending in use prevent default.... Im used to it with other key events too,,, enter key etc...

Comment: You didn't add the jQuery libraries

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Use jQuery if you like...

Using your Main.php UI file add some jQuery that calls eg: getDomainAvail.php.

So

1. create getDomainAvail.php file
2. in the new getDomainAvail.php file copy all the code given to you for the domain check and modify it with print statments of the resulting lookups.
3. then back in Main.php when your jquery ajax call gets returned with the result/response just assign it to a result element in the Main.php page.

Need more example than that? I can likely modify the code given to you if you want.

Cheers

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks for you reply men! I will appreciate it if you can modify the code for me, so that i will get the response without refreshing! If i can do anything for you just let me know! Greeetz

Comment: Thanks @Xcoder !  Rasclatt's answer below is very good and very very close to what I would have posted. Good luck, will be a cool user experience when you are done/

Comment: Hey Chad, Rasclatts example is not working for me. read the other comments

Comment: Ok, I emailed you. His script was really close from what I could see.

Comment: Bro thank you very much, i didn't tried your script yet, because Rasclatt script is working fine i think!!!!

Comment: Nice job guys :) thats always great.