# setTimeout() target function never fires

Tags: javascript

```
function redirectHome() {
    alert("here1");
    function setHref() {
        alert("here2");
            window.parent.location.href="fprIndex.html?action=edit&aspect=<%=request("aspect")%>&id=<%=request("Request_ID")%>";
    };

    document.forms["form1"].submit();
    var timer = setTimeout( setHref, 1000 );
}
```

redirectHome() is called via a button "onClick()" event.

The first alert "here1" is seen, but "here2" is never seen.

What's wrong?

What does work is if I simply:

```
function redirectHome() {
    document.forms["form1"].submit();   
    window.parent.location.href="fprIndex.html?action=edit&aspect=<%=request("aspect")%>&id=<%=request("Request_ID")%>";
}
```

What I'm to do is effect a 1 second delay from the time the form is submitted, to the time the redirect happens - for purely aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Doesn't `.submit()` submit a form, which sends your page on a roundtrip? Thus, eliminating the `location.href` from occurring because the page has already gone by before the timeout has completed?

Comment: When you open your console, do you see any errors?

Comment: Per your edit: Then move the `.submit()` line inside the `setHref()` method and forget the `location.href` line. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zxd59bz7/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is likely the problem is that the `submit()` call is causing a full post back to the server, which is similar to a page refresh and means the following javascript is not fired.

Comment: My form has onSubmit="return false", so that I can manually control the submission.  The form's submit button has onClick=redirectHome()'

Comment: When i simply do the .submit(), immediately followed by the .href=xxxxx, everything works, but it does it instantaneously.  I'm trying to effect a slight pause between the submit, and the href redir.

Comment: Part of the issue you're experiencing is due to the first answer in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543963/onsubmit-returning-false-is-not-working @KirbyL.Wallace the `onSubmit` event is not called when submitting the form programatically

Comment: My guess on the other issue is that the page isn't destroyed until the response begins, so the redirect works if you perform it right away because the browser hasn't recieved a response from the server yet, but once the response has begun, the page refreshes and you lose the `setTimeout` @KirbyL.Wallace

Comment: I'd suggest having the response from your sever perform the redirect instead of trying to do it on the client side @KirbyL.Wallace

Comment: Thanks, @JaredFarrish.  But I need to submit the form, then introduce a pause before the redirect.

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace - Redirect, as Will P suggested, from the server after the form is processed (which is what 99% of the code out there does), or submit the form with AJAX, and on response (if it's been less than 1 second), wait until it's been 1 second and redirect, or redirect immediately. Submitting the form as a Postback, then waiting one second (as the browser *redirects to the form action url*) and trying to redirect there is not the right approach.

Comment: @JaredFarrish.  Thanks.  I really should do it that way.  One thing I've learned in my many years of coding is that if a program is fighting against you writing it, it's probably a bad design.  ;-)

Comment: A redirect from the server was how this app worked initially.  Because it involved having to embed a form within a form, I moved the subform into an iframe (because you can't nest forms in html).  But issuing a redirect in the iframe only redirects the iframe.  I need to redirect to parent.

Comment: So, the server code includes a javascript that issues a "document.parent.location.href=" directive, leading to my current woes.  ;-)

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace try setting up a method on the parent window that does the set timeout + redirect, and just before the form submission call it using window.parent.[method name]. The parent shouldn't lose the setTimeout if it's called from there

Comment: @WillP.  If I redirect before submit, will I even get to the submit?  I will try and let you know.  Thanks.

Comment: The setTimeout should cover you on that, so the redirect will always happen after the call to submit

Comment: In the end, I just reverted to doing the redirect from the server.  Thanks.

Comment: Probably for the best.  Cheers!